# Start counting at zero by group

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'group': list('aaabbabc')})
>>> df
  group
0     a
1     a
2     a
3     b
4     b
5     a
6     b
7     c
```

I want to count the cumulative number of times each group has occurred. My desired output looks like this:

```
>>> df
  group  n
0     a  0
1     a  1
2     a  2
3     b  0
4     b  1
5     a  3
6     b  2
7     c  0
```

My initial approach was to do something like this:

```
df['n'] = df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: list(range(x.shape[0])))
```

Basically assigning a length *n* array, zero-indexed, to each group. But that has proven difficult to transpose and join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `groupby` + `cumcount`, and horizontally `concat` the new column:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, df.group.groupby(df.group).cumcount()], axis=1).rename(columns={0: 'n'})
    group   n
0   a   0
1   a   1
2   a   2
3   b   0
4   b   1
5   a   3
6   b   2
7   c   0
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `groupby` on column name, in this case `group` and then apply `cumcount` and finally add a column in dataframe with the result.

`df['n']=df.groupby('group').cumcount()`

```
 group  n
0   a   0
1   a   1
2   a   2
3   b   0
4   b   1
5   a   3
6   b   2
7   c   0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `apply` method by passing a `lambda` expression as parameter.

The idea is that you need to find out the `count` for a `group` as number of **appearances** for that `group` from the previous rows.

```
df['n'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(df['group'])[:int(x.name)].count(x['group']), axis=1)
```

Output

```
  group  n
0     a  0
1     a  1
2     a  2
3     b  0
4     b  1
5     a  3
6     b  2
7     c  0
```

**Note**: `cumcount` method is build with the help of the `apply` function.

You can read this in [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html).